# How to know which framework is used?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have been made to involve recently in a new project and I am completely unaware of which framework is used.After a long time I came to know spring is used because I saw some imports like

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable;
```

and I am sure spring is used.Now I am completely unaware of whether hibernate is used or jpa is used.When I asked my colleague then some are telling jpa is used and some are telling hibernate that means they are also confused.Can any body please throw some light regarding this.How would I know jpa or hibernate is used.

which packages should be imported specifically for jpa or hibernate.Any hint please

Comment: Check if you have persistence.xml file and what's inside.

Comment: @JakubHr Thanks for commenting but I dont have persistence.xml file.

Comment: These are few classes which frequently used in hibernate you can search them in your project
org.hibernate.HibernateException 
org.hibernate.Session 
org.hibernate.Transaction
org.hibernate.SessionFactory
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration

Comment: @JakubHr I can see some annotations `@PersistenceContext` does it mean I have used jpa?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is probably going on, is that the project is using Hibernate as an implemention of JPA.

To check and see is JPA is used, check the code and see whether or not you can find `EntityManager` or `EntityManagerFactory`

One way to see if Hibernate is being used, is to check the Spring configuration and see whether or not `HibernateJpaVendorAdapter` is used anywhere

In case you are have a persistence.xml file, `HibernateJpaVendorAdapter` shouldn't be present anywhere, and you can check if hibernate is mentioned anywhere in the file

Comment: Thanks for answering.I can see import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
 is used.so what does it mean?

Comment: That means that JPA is definitely being used. Check the rest of my answer to see if Hibernate is being used as well

Comment: Can you please tell me what is spring configuration and how to know if HibernateJpaVendorAdapter is used or not

Comment: Check any xml files or Java classes that have the @Configuration annotation

Comment: Just search the whole project for HibernateJpaVendorAdapter string

Comment: I can find @Configurable annotation but not `@configuration`

Comment: Ok, that means that the Spring configuration is in XML files. It is probably called something like, applicationContext.xml, config.xml, mvc-dispatcher.xml or something like that

Comment: yes you are 100% right.I have applicationcontext.xml,applicationcontext-security.xml and webmvc-config.xml.Now how to know?

Comment: Inside those file, check and see if you have HibernateJpaVendorAdapter anywhere

Comment: No HibernateJpaVendorAdapter  is not present in any of the above xml files

Comment: Do you have a bean with class org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean?

Comment: where can I find this bean?I mean in .java files or in .xml files?

Comment: ohh yes I have this in applicationcontext.xml file

Comment: Could you post it's <bean>...</bean> definition?

Comment: <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit"/>
       </bean>

Comment: Ok, this means that you should have persistence.xml file somewhere or a hibernate.cfg.xml somewhere. Have you found it?

Comment: ohh yes I found persistence.xml.

Comment: What is the content of persistence xml?

Comment: Does it say hibernate anywhere in there?

Comment: Ok, then you are using hibernate as a JPA implementation. Could you mark the answer as correct so future viewers can immediately tell it is correct without having to look at the comments? Thanks

Comment: I can see hibernate word in many lines but I can not find HibernateJpaVendorAdapter anywhere in in persistence.xml.Yes sure I will accept this answer and upvote also

Comment: Thanks! HibernateJpaVendorAdapter  would only be used if there where no persistence.xml present in the project

Answer (score 4):

Check out your project for `pom.xml`. This is configuration file for Maven, which handles dependencies (and how your project is build). With IDE or even with command line, you can display all used dependencies and frameworks.

Comment: Why did you make an assumption that he uses Maven?

Comment: yes maven is used.I am using spring tool suite.I have pom.xml.Please tell me how will I know now

Comment: @JakubHr because there is spring and hibernate with JPA, so there is very likely maven as well, it was my personal guess

Comment: @rocking right click on pom.xml, open with POM editor (should be the default editor) and select Dependency hierarchy. You'll see all frameworks being used. Use filter for quick search for jpa/hibernate.

Comment: I can see hibernate-jpa-api2.0 .So does this mean jpa is used?

Comment: Thank you very much in taking pain for helping but please dont mind for not accepting your answer as I think geoand's answer is having more info than other answer.I am upvoting your answer

Comment: It means that the hibernate implementation of JPA2 is present in the dependencies of the project and therefor (if configured correctly - which it is using persistence.xml) hibernate is used

Comment: Only the presence of some library is not sufficient to say, that something is used correctly. I agree that @geoand provided the best answer, +1 for him :)

Answer (score 2):

As you use Maven, you could list all dependencies (inclusive those transitive) using the [dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/list-mojo.html). Execute in the root folder the following command:

`mvn dependency:tree`

There you could check what version of hibernate is used and if hibernate-jpa is used.

Comment: Thanks for answering.You said execute in the root folder.I dont know how to execute and which is the root folder.Do you mean to execute in STS?

Comment: I mean the root folder of your project. Execute that command from console. Also if you find some answers good/helpful, vote them (I don't mean my answer). If one solves your problem, mark it as accepted.

Comment: Please dont mind for not accepting your answer becase I think geoand's answer gives more info but I have upvoted your answer also

Comment: I do not mind at all :) it is just important to show give feedback to the people.